# Putting the cards back into the tower

Tags: kingdomino

Playing Kingdomino is a lot of fun, however there is a moment I hate. Having to put the cards back into the card tower:

[image: The card tower]

If you're not careful, the cards get slanted and get stuck or just fall in the wrong direction. It can get quite irritating to put the cards back. Is there an obvious and easy method I'm missing to putting the cards back?

I've tried:

- Stacking the cards outside the box, opening the top and sliding them in.
- Sliding them in one at a time from the bottom slot
- Sliding them in one/several at a time from the top opening

Comment: I'll leave this a comment rather than an answer but It doesn't really answer how to get pieces back into the tower.  I wasn't aware there was a tower as when I played a friends copy he just shuffled them and made a stack.  Presumably to avoid using anything fiddly he didn't like (which he does a lot in games).  Another alternative could be to use a cloth bag and just draw the number you need each turn.  As I said left these as comments/suggestions as they aren.t technically answering what you asked.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I was hoping to avoid that due to the tower showing useful information about the number of cards, but if no-one provides a suitable answer, I guess a bag it is

Comment: I guess it depends if you think having the next number showing is useful or not?   For what is a light game I'd hope no one has bothered to memorise all the tiles and what is on the other side?  Apart from some info about tile distribution (which is in rules anyway I think)  is there a reason we must use tower other than for it looking nice?  I guess a bag is best option for you then if no better answer comes

Comment: Not the next numbering on the back of the tiles, the number of tiles left of that colour that is shown on the tower. For example, on the tower I know there are 10 green spaces with no crowns, 2 with a single crown 2 with a double. If I can see I have a lot of greens and no crowns and 3 green crown cards have gone, when the 4th comes up, I should strategically try to work to getting that card. To be fair, there's nothing wrong with just having the tower standing by the board for reference and using a bag, but would be nice to use the tower if I can find a workable way

Comment: Wait, is this just regular Kingdomino? I have Kingdomino, and I've played on more recent printings also, and I've never seen any card tower like this.

Comment: And another non-answer similar to StartPlayer's comment; given that I've never seen this tower; we always just leave the pieces in the box and pull them out directly from there. No need for a bag. We keep the back of the rulebook visible for players to see the tile color distribution; if you have this tower showing that also, you can simply keep it visible to the players also.

Comment: Seems I have an upgraded 2nd version of the game:  https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1851011/upgrade-kit-whats. I won it at a recent gaming festival and thought it was standard.

Comment: Does the front part slide off?

Comment: @Acccumulation Not easily, the top and bottom of it slide off to give an opening to put the cards in

Answer (score 3):

If you look closely, there is a magnetized side of the tower that simply swings open. This allows you to place the entire stack of tiles in the tower at once.

[image]

Comment: A picture of it opened would probably be better.

Comment: I don't own this particular item, so I'm limited to the picture provided by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

If there's enough clearance, thus should work: get some tagboard or similar material, cut it to be a bit wider than the cards are long (its total width should be slightly less than the length of the cards plus twice the width of the cards). Draw two centered (that is, halfway between them should be the center of the tagboard) vertical lines on the tagboard a card length apart. Bend the tagboard up on the lines to make 90 degree angles. You should now have a card-size box with the ends and top open. Put the cards in the box. Put the tower on its side, slide the box into it. Hold the cards in the tower while you slide the box out.